# Is 'also' necessary here? ("Changes in the coach's ideas also necessitate a change in the way players communicate during the game.")

Tags: meaning

I am struggling between the two versions of a sentence. To be precise, I was wondering which sentence is more native-like/idiomatic? Do I really need the word *also* there?

A:

> Changes in the coach's ideas **also** necessitate a change in the way players communicate during the game.

B:

> Changes in the coach's ideas necessitate a change in the way players communicate during the game.

Comment: Good question. If all the coach's new ideas 'necessitate a change' in communication, you don't need **also**. If not, it's useful.

Comment: **also** would typically refer to something stated previously. *When a coach's ideas change, the way players communicate during the game must also change.*

Comment: Impossible to answer without more (prior) context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

If a previous sentence had described some result(s) of changes in the coach's ideas, you use "also" here to indicate that this is an additional consequence.

If there wasn't such a preceding sentence, "also" is optional but not required. You might use it to suggest that there are obvious consequences that are unstated, and you're adding a non-obvious result.